# How can I create a method that will print LINQ query results?

Tags: c#, linq, methods

I need to create a method that will print my query results so that I wont have to retype printing results out after each query. I've written a method that seems to work until I specify that I only want to return a specific variable instead of all of them in a list.

```
static void Print(this IEnumerable<Game> source)
    {

        foreach(var q in source)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        var count = source.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("The query pulls: {0} results.", count);
        Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

This method correctly prints out the list of query results with this type of query:

`var query4 = games.Where(g => g.PeakPlayers >100000) 
                  .Where(g => g.ReleaseDate > new DateTime(01/01/2013));
        Print(query4);`

It throws an error when specifying what I want it to select in the results:

`var query10 = games.Where(g => g.Price == 0).Select(g => g.Name);
        Print(query10)`

Comment: In the last one, query10 isn't an IEnumerable of `Game`. It's an IEnumerable of whatever type `Name` is - probably `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your method more generic:

```
static void Print<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{

    foreach(var q in source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(q); // implicitly calls T.ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    var count = source.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("The query pulls: {0} results.", count);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Then you can pass it a list of complex objects or just a single property:

```
games.Select(g => g.Name).Print();
```

If you want to improve this even more, you can add support for objects and structures by using reflection to get a list of properties, looping through the properties, and printing the values in a row for each item.

Or, you can add an optional parameter that lets you define how to "print" each item (bypassing the implicit `ToString`):

```
static void Print<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<string, T> toString)
{

    foreach(var q in source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(toString(q));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    var count = source.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("The query pulls: {0} results.", count);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and pass in your "toString" function:

```
games.Print(g => "Name: " + g.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method `static void Print(this IEnumerable<Game> source)` expects an `IEnumerable<T>` of type `Game`:

Here you are selecting only the `Name` attribute: `var query10 = games.Where(g => g.Price == 0).Select(g => g.Name);`
Which I assume is a string, which violates the parameter of `IEnumerable<Game>`